# What is the adverb form of event?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the adverb form of event? As an example:

> Aggregate these pictures by their semantics: aggregate **semantically**.
>
> Aggregate these pictures by the events they may belong to: aggregate ________.

What word or phrase can fill in the blank?

EDIT: To provide some context: By event I mean by instance of birthday party/political rally/sports event/tech conference etc. in a large, unstructured collection of photos belonging to one of these.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49024/discussion-on-question-by-abhijat-biswas-what-is-the-adverb-form-of-event).

Answer (score 27):

## Adverbs are over-hyped

It turns out that one can always create an adverbial prepositional phrase using the noun:

> Aggregate these pictures by the events they may belong to: aggregate **by event**.

This way you do not need to create a free-standing adverb.  You don’t even need an adjective (like *event-based, event-driven, eventful*) this way, and the simple noun is just fine.

From Wikipedia:

> In linguistics, an *adverbial phrase* is a group of two or more words operating adverbially, meaning that their syntactic function is to modify a verb, an adjective, or an adverb. Adverbial phrases ("AdvP" in syntactic trees) are phrases that do the work of an adverb in a sentence.

When you need to describe how or when or where or why something takes place, ***all you need is a constituent that functions adverbially***.  You don’t need a literal adverb.

The only time you truly need a single word of some particular part of speech is occasionally when writing computer programs. In actual language used by actual humans in actual speech, we combine words into phrases to convey infinitely more than ever can be expressed in a single word alone.  And that’s not hyperbole, either.

Comment: Great! That's it.

Comment: Don't you mean “Adverbs are over-hypedly”?

Comment: Even in computer programming I have a hard time imagining why you could not use two words. You might need to run them together (removing any space between them), but there are conventions for doing that.

Comment: Thanks! Does providing context (in the edit) change anything in your answer? Are you able to suggest another word with a more idiomatic adverb form that conveys the same meaning?

Comment: You mean that instead of "adverbially", you could have just used "as an adverb"?

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use ***[thematic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thematic) :***

> - of, relating to, or consisting of a theme or themes.

- *Aggregate the pictures **thematically.***

Dictionary.com

Comment: That may be too vague for OP’s purposes.  There may be many different themes possible.  Maybe i’ve got pictures from WWI, WWII and Vietnam, but a possible thematic aggregation could be city, country, or portraits, fighting scenes, hospital scenes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If an adverb is to fit the blanks, I suggest [**situationally**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/situationally) or [**contextually**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contextually).

> - "by way of situation"
> - "in a contextual manner; with reference to context"

Aggregate them situationally/contextually

Answer (score 5):

In your example, *semantics* and *events they may belong to* are characteristics of the pictures. Therefore an adverb that modifies the verb *aggregate* does not make sense. It reads ok for *semantically* but that's coincidental and as @FumbleFingers points out, it won't work for other words.

This might be clearer:

> Aggregate these pictures by:
>
> - Their semantics
> - Events they are related to

or, shorter:

> Aggregate these pictures by:
>
> - Semantics
> - Related events

but it's hard to tell without knowing more of the background to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I agree with your answer. I would use "per event" or "by event".

Comment: I think event-wise works unless it is un-idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate *timewise*.

Definition: With respect to time (https://www.wordnik.com/words/timewise)

**Edit**: If there are multiple events at the same time, but in different locations,you could aggregate time and themewise, or time and locationwise.  (The squiggles under these tell me I'm not in the dictionary any more.)